# Android activity restart with same Objectreferences

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing, restart

i already read the question [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android) . But it does not really help me.

I've two activities. The Second gets updated from an Async_Task, which holds a few Threads which i cannot just restart. 
The Problem i got is, that rotating my Device forces an Activity-restart, which means i loose my Reference to the Async_Task.
Is there any possibility to pass Objektreferences from one activity to another?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your reference static, or see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: Thanks! I think the Link will do it! But how can i pass an object with running threads with a static reference? Maybe i don't get it, but does not matter at the moment:)

Comment: I prefer the static method.  So, on your Activity class do static MyActivity ACTIVE_INSTANCE;  Then onCreate() do ACTIVE_INSTANCE = this and onDestroy do ACTIVE_INSTANCE = null.  Then after your async task has finished do ACTIVE_INSTANCE.someMethod().  That should work across activity restarts.